# Triangle side tabs with border in css+html

Tags: html, css, tabs

I need something like this 
[triangle side navigation tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7VSL.jpg), I tried to do this, using :after

```
.tabs input + label:after{
content:"";
float:left;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:-12px;
width:0;
height:0;
border-top: 15px solid black;
border-left: 11px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 16px solid black;    
}
```

But I had something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQkB5.png)

I need triangle side with a border for 1 px, thanks for help.
+1 if you include a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a `::before` pseudo element to create two tringles sitting on top of one-other using borders with a darker color.
- Next, cover the unnecessary parts with an `::after` pseudo element with the same color as your elements. This can be done with the same rules as the `::before` element, positioned `1px` less to the left, to create a `1px` wide arrow
- Finally, for the tip of the arrow, add a `1px` `box-shadow` to the right edge of both of the pseudo elements with the same color. Note: if you want the arrow to be wider, the shadow should be adjusted accordingly.
- Remember to exclude the `:first-of-type` to avoid having an arrow before the first element.

Code:

```
li:not(:first-of-type)::before, li:not(:first-of-type)::after{
  content:'';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 10px;
  border-color: blue transparent;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 blue;
}
li:not(:first-of-type)::after{
  left: -9px;
  border-color: lightblue transparent;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 lightblue;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/r5enysmf/